# Need space between image/text HTML

Tags: html, css

I need more space between image and buttons.

Here is what i'we tried: `<br>` but it takes much space on html code because i need to write this: `<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>` to get enough space. Can someone help?

[image: THIS IS IMAGE]

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is add margin or to your css file for the button elements

It would look something like :

```
button {
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
```

In your css file. If you're doing your css inline (hopefully not), then you would define it in the style of your element.

Comment: Padding would likely make the buttons larger, a margin would probably be a better choice.

Comment: that is a good point, will update accordingly

Comment: @StefanĐorđević you should accept/mark it as a answer.

Comment: I did that much time ago.